# PHP phalcon, load view from database

Tags: php, phalcon

Can i load view from database, instead of phtml file? Basically i wish to have views customized for each company registered on the website (design etc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but this will require some work. You'll need to [create custom template engine adapter](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#creating-your-own-template-engine-adapter), which loads template from DB and renders it, probably using eval().